# How to edit spring xml file

Tags: shell, unix

I'm learning Shell scripting, so i have spring XML file so  i want to change the value in bean tag

```
<bean class="com.swacorp.revmgmt.inventoryadjustment.service.impl.rules.effect.AuSetterEffect">
           <property name="factPropertyName" value="vml.au.K"/>
           <property name="expression" value="15"/>
            <property name="addIfNotPresent" value="true"/>
        </bean>
```

how to change property value --
     property name="expression" value="15".
this tag have different bean also

Please help me

Comment: why don't you do some research and try something for yourself? and if it's not working you can ask exactly what problem do you have and provide some examples / sample code

Comment: This is a duplicate of one of *your own* questions.